# problem with exchange server hosted on UCS server

Tags: cisco

here we are have 2 UCS server B series, with 7 hosts distributed as 5 hosts on the first UCS and 2 hosts on the other UCS. 1 year ago we move our exchange servers to be hosted on one host of the 7. our exchange solution is consisted of two CAS servers which visualized by one IP address and one MAC address . recently this virtual IP is not pingable and this problem binding till we move the exchange servers from host to other. any advice could help

also i not that when i move the CASs from host to other and Virual Ip start respond it give the next result from the FIs itself

```
64 bytes from 10.3.252.185: icmp_seq=1 ttl=127 time=0.313 ms
64 bytes from 10.3.252.185: icmp_seq=1 ttl=127 time=0.511 ms (DUP!)
64 bytes from 10.3.252.185: icmp_seq=2 ttl=127 time=0.263 ms
64 bytes from 10.3.252.185: icmp_seq=2 ttl=127 time=0.369 ms (DUP!)
```

Comment: We need a lot more details to answer this question. Please provide the equipment's configurations. A diagram may help.

Comment: With 2 UCS do you mean 2 chassis (connected to the same FI pair) or 2 FI pairs ? How are they connected to the rest of the network? When the problem happens, where does the ping fail: outside the vlan, inside the vlan, does it also fail when you ping from the other UCS servers? Do the CAS also have another ip address and is that still reachable? Do you see the mac address in the mac address table of the FI's ?

Comment: BTW It could be useful to provide a link to some reading material about how this stuff with the single MAC address works exactly, I for one am not familiar with that.

Comment: yes we have 2 chassis connected to two FIs , they connected to the rest of the network through nexus 3048 switches then the core switches . all servers on the hosts (VMs) are in the vlan of the servers . yes the non virtual IPs are pingable

Comment: we treat the connections provided to Vms by two QOS one of them is 1G for management the other is 9G for Data traffic

Comment: are you could access the UCS java application . may you check any fault occurred on the hosts

Comment: i couldn't see any fault on the hosts

Comment: So the 2 CAS are also VMs? What kind of virtual switch do you use?  Are these 2 CAS servers doing NLB in unicast or multicast mode? Are the FI in end host mode or switch mode?

Comment: yes both are running over VM hosted on esxi6 , NLB is multicast (i configured static arp on my core switch to map the virtual ip to the virtual mac), FI in end host mode

Comment: Using nexus1000v as vswitch?

Comment: no we don't use it